# Unauthorized 401 Error on accessing the endpoint

Tags: azure

I have this nagging error message on accessing an endpoint on azure portal.
Any one could help?

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
cache-control: none
content-length: 0
content-security-policy: script-src 'self'
date: Tue, 23 Nov 2021 16:47:15 GMT
expect-ct: max-age=604800,enforce
ocp-apim-apiid: cash-code
ocp-apim-operationid: generate-cashcode
ocp-apim-subscriptionid: master

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please describe which type of Azure resource endpoint you are trying to access - via Portal UI or some script / code? If later, then share snippet.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was simply a case of using the wrong "secret" i.e. I accidentally used the SecretID instead of the value of the secret.

That was allowing me to get a code without an error message, but the code was not actually valid even though it looked like a proper code, and all I got back was the infamous 401 without a clue as to why it was happening.